# Control Events- Revit API

Tags: revit-api

I would like to control events of Load Families and Create Type with revit api. Someone can give me a direction ? I don't understand very well the documentation that I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to subscribe to an event by creating an event listener in the `IExternalApplication` `OnStartup` method.

```
public class AppCommand : IExternalApplication
{
    public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        application.ControlledApplication.FamilyLoadedIntoDocument += OnFamilyLoaded;

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

Next you need a handler for that event:

```
private void OnFamilyLoaded(object sender, FamilyLoadedIntoDocumentEventArgs args)
{
    // do work here
}
```

When finished you need to unregister the event handler:

```
public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
{
     application.FamilyLoadedIntoDocument -= OnFamilyLoaded;

     return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

The other events available that you can subscribe to are these:

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018/b69e9d33-3c49-e895-3267-7daabab85fdf.htm

Cheers!